# MDX to get last Sunday and Saturday

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I built a SSRS 2005 report on a SSAS 2005 cube. The report has start date and end date parameters from Time dimension. I need to set the default values to be last Sunday and last Saturday separately. (financial week is from Sunday to Saturday)

E.g.

Start date: [Time].[Day].&[20140309]
End date: [Time].[Day].&[20140315]

How can I do it dynamically? I mean for this week is above dates, but for next week, it should be 16 March, 22 March. I know how to do it in T-SQL, which will involve some calculation with system date, but MDX?

Comment: Do you want to have the last Saturday and the last Sunday contained in the ` [Time].[Day]` hierarchy? Or the Saturday before and up to today, and the Sunday of today or the next one after today?

Comment: @FrankPl The Time hierarchy has financial year, financial week, and day. You mean I put last Sunday, last Saturday in for each row?

Comment: No, my question was "how do i determine what the 'last' Saturday/Sunday is"? Can I assume that you need the last Saturday and Sunday contained in the time dimension? Do I have to take the current date into account?

Comment: @FrankPl I mean for this financial week (16 - 22 Mar), every time the report opens it should have default start date and end date to 20140309 and 20140315. Or for next financial week (23 - 29 Mar), every time the report opens it should have default start date and end date to 20140316 and 20140322.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some [VBA Date functions available in MDX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510163.aspx):

```
StrToMember('[Time].[Day].&['
            + Format(DateAdd('d', - DatePart('w', Now(), 1), Now()), 'yyyyMMdd')
            + ']'
           )
```

should give you the last Saturday before today, and

```
StrToMember('[Time].[Day].&['
            + Format(DateAdd('d', - DatePart('w', Now(), 1) - 6, Now()), 'yyyyMMdd')
            + ']'
           )
```

the last Sunday before that.

The second argument of `DateAdd('d', ...)` is the number of days to add. And as this is negative here, we go back in time that many days. `DatePart('w', ...)` returns the weekday number (Sunday = 1, Monday = 2, ...). Thus, if you subtract "weekday number" days from today, luckily you are already at last Saturday. And subtracting six more days, you arrive at the last Sunday before that.